# SELECT SUM WHERE multiple values even if are equals

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to sum the duration of multiple selection.
BMPR-00028.mp4 = 7 seconds

```
SELECT SUM(durata_video_secondi) as durata_video_secondi
from catalog
WHERE file_video in ('BMPR-00028.mp4','BMPR-00028.mp4')
```

with this query the result is 7 but I want the SUM of values so I want 14 as result.
I try with

```
SELECT SUM(durata_video_secondi) as durata_video_secondi 
from catalog 
WHERE file_video ='BMPR-00028.mp4' OR file_video ='BMPR-00028.mp4'
```

but the result is always 7 because the values are the same. But I need the sum of values so I need 14 as result.
Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: You are referencing the same video twice. It will return only 1 result and the sum of which seems to be 7.

Comment: You have a list of videos and you want all of them to be counted even if there are duplicates?

Comment: Put the value twice in a cte/temporary table/etc, and JOIN.

Comment: @Schwern yes, I want all of them even if are duplicates or more

Comment: @jarlh I have a list... So I don't know if some are duplicates or not... So I have to parsing ?

Comment: Skip the parsing, just join. (Like Schwern's answer below.) 200 values, put them in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter how many times you reference the same row, the query will only return one row. SQL is declarative; it doesn't iterate through the list of `file_video`, you're asking it for all the rows which match the list. There's only one row that matches no matter how many times you ask for it.

Instead, you need to turn the values into rows and join against them; this ensures there is one row for every value, even duplicates. You can do this by inserting them into a temp table, or for small numbers of values you can join with a subquery and [`union all`](https://www.w3schools.com/mySQl/sql_ref_union.asp).

```
select sum(durata_video_secondi)
from catalog c
join (
  select 'BMPR-00028.mp4' as file_video
  union all
  select 'BMPR-00028.mp4' as file_video
) v on c.file_video = v.file_video;
```

[Demonstration](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9ovDLa86us3vTbALefB7aX/0).

Comment: Thanks, but there are no efficiency problem if I have 200 select?

Comment: @pette Shouldn't be. If there is, insert them into a temp table and join with it. Try it.

Comment: Thanks!! No efficiency problem with 200 select