# How get a Value even if result is not found in the DB mysql

Tags: mysql, left-join, common-table-expression, union-all

I need to find the right query to get a value even if the data not exist in the db.

I have my table named "prova":

| it | en | de |
| --- | --- | --- |
| data | data |  |
| riga | row | linie |
| parola |  |  |

If I query:

```
SELECT en,de FROM `prova` WHERE `it` IN ("data","riga");
```

The resoult is:

| en | de |
| --- | --- |
| data |  |
| row | linie |

And it's ok!

**BUT**

```
SELECT en,de FROM `prova` WHERE `it` IN ("data","riga","ciao","parola");
```

The resoult is:

| en | de |
| --- | --- |
| data |  |
| row | linie |

Is as expected in the standard mysql but for me is a problem.

**The the desired result is:**

| en | de |
| --- | --- |
| data | not found |
| row | linie |
| not found | not found |
| not found | not found |

## Why I want this?

I need to perform a query with an array of string, actually I need to query one by one string, and check if the query is empty. The size and the order of the resulted array should be equal to the given array.

Actually I need to perform 8700 queries, this will help me to decrease the queries number to 8.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure in your desired result? You really want `not found` in the ***first*** column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a cte that returns the array of strings with a number that corresponds to the order of the string in the results and a `LEFT` join of the table:

```
WITH cte(id, word) AS (VALUES
  ROW(1, 'data'), ROW(2, 'riga'), ROW(3, 'ciao'), ROW(4, 'parola')
)
SELECT COALESCE(p.en, 'not found') en,
       COALESCE(p.de, 'not found') de
FROM cte c LEFT JOIN prova p
ON p.it = c.word
ORDER BY c.id;
```

Or, with `UNION ALL` for versions of MySql prior to 8.0 without the cte support:

```
SELECT COALESCE(p.en, 'not found') en,
       COALESCE(p.de, 'not found') de
FROM (
  SELECT 1 id, 'data' word UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'riga' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3, 'ciao' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4, 'parola'
) t
LEFT JOIN prova p ON p.it = t.word
ORDER BY t.id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e44db09fd4ca8b9167aa0e394f2f548c).

Comment: This is really elegant. You and Schwern are so fast! I was thinking through this question and was considering a temp table. It didn't occur to me to use `values`. Thank you.

Comment: Is the first time I see cte, and sincerly I don't undestand as weel how this query work,but I will study how cte work. Another problem, I'm using mysql version 5.5 and I get error on VALUES, what's wrong with?? (if you switch to 5.5 in your example you can see the probelm

Comment: @StefanoMartini you are using a version of MySql that is almost 12 years old. Check my 2nd query.

Comment: @forpas yes, my bad, I format the pc and I didn't upgrade mysql! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use `coalesce` to fill in a null value with a default.

```
select
  coalesce(en, 'not found'),
  coalesce(de, 'not found')
...
```

For the second part, how to make all the `in` values show up as rows, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71579841/14660).